# Most of the Folders On Hidden Share Not Showing

Tags: windows, network-share

I have a hidden share that I access \servername\hiddenshare$

I can only see one folder out of about 10 that I should see. When I log into another computer I see all the folders. So I believe it's a problem with my PC. It's worth noting that a lot of these folders appear to be shortcuts but do not redirect me to another LAN location when I enter into them.

Comment: In addition to the user permissions that yagmoth555 mentions, here's another thing to check: Perhaps the "missing" folders have their `Hidden` attribute set. And your first PC does not have "Show Hidden Items" enabled, but the other PC does.

Comment: The hidden attribute is not set on any of the folders in this directory. I do not have the "Show Hidden Items" checkbox checked on both machines and on one machine I only see one folder and on the other machine I see all the folders.

Answer (score 0):

Validate what user you use on the computer. Folder listing is affected by the user account that map or open the drive map.

If the user does not have security to see those files the system simply hide them.

Comment: I don't think it's a permissions issue. I compared the permissions on the one folder I can see to the other folders I can't see and everything appears to be exactly the same. Again, one one machine I only see one folder. On another machine I can see all the folders. Also, on the machine where I only see one folder the folder appears as a normal folder. On the machine where I can see all the folders the folder appears as a shortcut.

Comment: @Charlie If you create a file, does it appear on both computer ? I wonder if a hosts file trick, or netbios error make your pc connect to the wrong endpoint